# jquery play sound when bookmarklet is released

Tags: jquery, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet and I would like to play a sound when a user releases it on the bookmark bar.

This is the code i have.

```
<audio id="applause" preload="auto" autobuffer>
    <source src="applause.mp3" />
    <source src="applause.ogg" />
</audio>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#bookmarklet a').mouseup(function() {
        $('#applause')[0].play();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seems unlikely that the bookmarking action would trigger an event to which the web site would be able to react. So most probably it's not possible to play a sound when the bookmarklet is saved.